# Open Source Web Application Security Tools

Tags: security, web-applications

any suggestion that I can achieve the following goal.

1. User download a zip folder from server.
2. After unzipping the file, user need to enter username and password in order to authenticate itself before open and viewing any files in the folder. It will launch a script to validate from the authentication server.
3. User also are restricted to copy out any files from that folder.

Comment: Not the right forum to ask the question , since the answers can be opiniated .. Would suggest that you do your research and evaluate a few tools as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi, may I know any forum for this security related discussion?

Comment: You should refer to OWASP ....